# My if statements always return true

Tags: if-statement

```
    if ((x != A) || (x != a )|| ( x != B) || (x != b) || ( x != C) || (x != c) || (x != D) || (x != d) || ( x != F) || (x != f))
    {
    System.out.println("Points: -1");
     return true;
    }
    else
    {
    System.out.println("hi");
     return false;
    }
```

For some reason I can't get this to return anything else but true.

Comment: Well, as is, x does not equal any of the other variables so it will return true

Comment: x represents an inputted char

Comment: If `A`, `a`, `B`, `b`, ... are characters you want to compare against, you want to put those in apostrophes `'A'`, `'a'`, ... In general, it helps if you provide a Minimal Working Example that will actually compile and run. http://sscce.org/

Comment: I tried that its still always returning true.

Comment: @KevinBarrett for what x do you think it should be false?

Comment: @KevinBarrett Check out my code below, user902383 is right.

Answer (score 4):

Take the first two conditions: `(x != A) || (x != a )`.

What your saying here is, return `true` if `x` is either not equal to `A` or to `a`.

Assuming `x == A`, the first condition will return false and the second true. Thus your whole if-condition will return true.

Likewise for `x == a`. Here the first condition yields `true` and so does the if-condition.

What you probably mean is to connect all those conditions using `AND` or `&&` instead of `OR` (`||`).

Comment: Assuming of course that `A != a`.

Comment: @hammar Of course. But as OP noted in the comments, the values shall represent single characters.

Comment: no I need them to to be or because the user only inputs one character

Comment: @KevinBarrett Maybe you should post the code as well, where `x` is defined, read, ...

Comment: I'm trying to it won't let me repost it.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ((x != 'A') || (x != 'a' ) ....
          ^ missing quotes
```

But even then, x can either be 'A' or 'a' or neither. With the **OR** evalution, you will always end up with **TRUE** as x will always **NOT** be one of those other values you are testing.

Do `(x != 'A') && (x != 'a' ) ...`

Answer (score 0):

yes it will be always true
lets just concider part of your expression `((x != A) || (x != a ) ...`

if x=A, then first statement is false, but other one is true, and as you have disjunction so you will always get true.

to get false you need x=A and x=a, which might be bit impossible

Comment: Ok so I need it to = one or the other

Comment: yes you need to do x==A || x==a or !(x!=A && x!=a)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CtCqe/2/

Using regex might be better, not sure if the input of the user is only a single character or not.

Html

```
<div id="result">Result</div>
<input type='text'/>
<div id="pressed"></div>
```

Jquery

```
$('input').on('change input', function(){

   var x = $(this).val();



if((x == 'A') || (x == 'a' )|| ( x == 'B') || (x == 'b') || ( x == 'C') || (x == 'c') || (x == 'D') || (x == 'd') || ( x == 'F') || (x == 'f')){
    $('#result').html('False');
    $(this).val('');
}else{
    $('#result').html('True');
    $(this).val('');
}

$('#pressed').html(x);

});
```